# Why does elixir not have typed based methods work on the instance?

Tags: elixir

Just learning elixir and I want to understand why elixir chose to be so verbose and does things based on helper methods like:

```
String.upcase(name)
```

instead of doing it like:

```
name.upcase
```

In Scala you can do `name.toUpperCase`, and it will still return a new variable since it is immutable.

Anyhow, just trying to understand the reason for this approach as I am sure this is a reason.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Elixir is a functional language. This would mean that `String` is a file and `upcase/1` is a function and the variable`name` has no context of `upcase/1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no such things as objects or methods in Elixir. There's only data and functions that can act on that data - the two are separate.

Comment: I was going to answer with something along that lines but I wasn't sure how close Elixir is to Erlang.

Comment: On that level there's very little difference between the two.

Comment: Consider Elixir as Erlang with better syntax and more built-in features.

Comment: @PatNowak I'm not going to go as far as saying it has a better syntax just different. I personally don't mind the Erlang syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For the few cases where you want to dispatch a function based on the type of an argument, Elixir provides [protocols](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html).

This is the machinery behind functions like `to_string` that work on many different data types:

```
for something <- [1, DateTime.utc_now(), "hello"], do: something |> to_string
["1", "2017-07-31 02:23:54.773667Z", "hello"]
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers cover this question quite nicely, I'd like to add a bit on some of the underlying theoretical issues.

Scala is what I'd call a hybrid language--primarily functional but bringing forward lots of OO ideas as well. I would also include F#, Swift and Kotlin under that rubric as well.  One OO idea is the notion of invoking a method on a particular object--the *obj.method* notion you mention.  As you've realized there's nothing that forces that code to mutate the value it's working on. That is rather than change the string which is being upper-cased, a new string is returned.

However it's hard for developers to break old habits and one habit is expecting that notation to mutate the object (rather than making a copy of the object and changing the copy). Many of us have years of Java or C# which has shaped our expectations of how OO should work--whether it must work that way or not.

At this point, it just feels as if making a developer call a function from a module and pass the value that he or she wants to operate on simply helps a developer to start to develop a better mental model of what's actually going on.  And while the *obj.method* notation may be more familiar it can also lead developers to an incorrect expectation of what will happen; i. e. it can lead to an expectation of a mutable object.